# How to detect the context of homepage for a wordpress mu sub-blog

Tags: multisite

I'd like to do this when clicking on home icon :

- if we are not on the homepage of a sub-blog, go to the homepage of the sub-blog
- if we are on the homepage of a sub-blog, go to the homepage of the whole site

I'm beginner and don't know how to detect the context of homepage for a wordpress mu sub-blog, any idea, thanks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test using the following conditionals

```
//if you aren't on the main site, and aren't on the homepage
if (!is_main_site() && (!is_front_page() && !is_home())) {
  print "<a href='sub-blog-homepage'>home</a>";
}
//if you aren't on the main site, and aren on the homepage
if (!is_main_site() && (is_front_page() && is_home())) {
  print "<a href='main-site-homepage'>home</a>";
}
```

Also depending on how your sub-blog homepage is configured, you could use either `is_front_page()`, `is_home()`.

Comment: Thanks guy for the code will try it as soon as possible :)

Comment: My pleasure! :)